# id field without autoincrement option in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a DB migration like so:

```
 class CreateParticipations < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table(:participations, :primary_key => 'Seat')  do |t|      
          t.integer :Seat
          t.string :Nickname
          t.string :Clan
          t.string :FirstName
          t.string :LastName
          t.string :Email
          t.boolean  :Payed

          t.timestamps
        end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :participations
      end
    end
```

Now, seat is created with an Auto increment. However, I do not want that. I want it without an auto increment. I will define Seat myself in my Logic.

I have been looking around but I cannot find how to disable auto_increment.

How do I do this? Except for manually doing it in MySQL.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do this? It goes against the convention that works very well throughout rails and will cause you lots of extra work in the rest of your application making this exception to the rule work everywhere. Perhaps "Seat" in just a field on this table with a unique index instead. Unless you need this to adapt to a legacy schema of some sort this is usually a bad idea. Sadly I don't know the actual answer to your question.

Comment: I know this is animating the dead, here, but a relatively trivial example might be a model that is tied to a non-Rails service that manages ids within that service. It would have no need for auto-increment within Rails, because it would make the most sense to tie the Rails representation to the non-Rails service representation's id, rather than generating yet ANOTHER id and managing ANOTHER set of constraints.

However, without more details as to the necessity in the asker's original circumstance, I would generally agree with you.

Answer (score 17):

For the record, if you absolutely need to do this (it shouldn't happen often), here's the way to do a non-autoincrementing primary key with the Rails migration DSL:

```
create_table(:table_name, :id => false) do |t|
  t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```

That will work for MySQL anyway, if your DB uses different syntax to specify a primary key, replace the `:options => 'PRIMARY KEY'` with whatever that is.

Comment: Note that this still has some issues, because Rails treats the name id a bit magically. While it breaks naming conventions, in terms of having to code around stuff, naming the primary key field something other than id is probably preferable.

Comment: If I name it to something else, would I need to change my route.rb, Cancan `load_resource` and so on? Thanks~

Comment: FYI, if you still try it after SO MANY YEARS - it doesn't work in Rails 6 :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is 3 years old, but incase anyone is wondering 3 years later, like I was, all you do is "change_column" in the event the table is already created:

```
change_column(:table_name, :id, :integer, :null => false)
```

This should work in Rails 2.x and 3.x.

O

Answer (score 1):

Not saying its a good idea, but here's how I did it for SQLite3 - just replace that SQLiteAdapter with your DB's adapter - you might do this cleaner/short with a call to define_method

```
class AbstractAdapter
end

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class SQLiteAdapter < AbstractAdapter
      def supports_autoincrement?
        false
      end
    end
  end
end

<then you migration>
```

or

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :table do |t|
      ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteAdapter.send :define_method, :supports_autoincrement? do false end
      t.integer etc
    end
  end
end
```

Of course just change the adapter for other db's

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use rails' id key and manually add an index called Seat?

I've seen some hacks just to get rails to -work- on non-increment-pk databases.  I don't think it's an option.  If I recall, that's how rails accesses all its per-row functionality.

Honestly, how -absolutely- do you need that slight boost in efficiency of ignoring rails' structure?

I think the real answer is "you can't."  Activerecord has a few things it will not bend on.

Comment: I am porting an ASP.MVC application where I had my BLL and DAL custom logic, but it makes sense now