# ruby on rails id not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is going against ruby on rails conventions, but my id of this table doesn't need to auto-increment and I'm setting it through the logic. However, it's not saving to the database. Everything getting saved is saving as null for the id.

```
def self.up
 create_table :probes, :id => false do |t|
  t.string :id
  t.string :name
  t.integer :user_id
  t.boolean :online
  t.timestamps
 end
end

<% form_for @probe do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
 <p>
  <%= f.label "Site name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </p>
     <p style="margin-left: 10%">
  <%= f.label "Probe Key" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :id, :value => @token %>
 </p>
 <p style="margin-left: 20%">
  <%= link_to "Back to List", probes_path %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit",:style => "margin-left: 75px;" %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Is this even possible? Or is there somewhere besides the new.html.erb file that I should be changing/checking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the :id field is not accessible for mass-assignment. you need to set it manually with

> `@probe.id = params[:probe][:id]`

in your controller code.

(It also *might* work if you add `:id` to your `attr_accessible` list, and in general you should set `attr_accessible` for every model that is directly mass-assigned from form parameters, but w/o testing I'm not sure if it will work, you might still have to manually set `:id`)

Comment: I have  
@Probe = Probe.new(params[:probe])  
@Probe = params[:probe][:id]  

In my controller, but still not working. Here is my entire create method:  
def create
   @user = current_user
   @probe = Probe.new(params[:probe])
 @probe.id = params[:probe][:id]

    @probe = @user.probes.create!(params[:probe])
    if @probe.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created probe."
      redirect_to probes_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

Comment: Well, i'm retarded, haha. I forgot to pass in @probe in the create method. However now i'm getting an error about strigify keys...undefined method `stringify_keys!'

Comment: And that was happening because i was using create which only accepts a hash. @Probe.save worked fine. Problem fixed.

Comment: Nope, attr_accessible doesn't work. Only direct assignment, f*ck it.

Answer (score 1):

From AdminMyServer on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517869/id-field-without-autoincrement-option-in-
migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517869/id-field-without-autoincrement-option-in-migration)

```
#using a number
create_table(:table_name, :id => false) do |t|  
  t.integer :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end

#using as string, like the question (why?)
create_table(:table_name, :id => false) do |t|  
  t.string :id, :options => 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```

Comment: This is integer, rails doesn't like non-numeric primary keys. At least that's what I'm reading. Is there a way to set a string as a primary key?

Comment: i didn't notice you were using string... is there a good reason why?

Comment: The ID is a UUID generated, and I'm doing this because belongs_to can't have a primary key which I need, so I'm making this the ID so I can join my tables together correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `ActiveRecord` instances are set up so that the `id` attribute cannot be set through mass-assignment which is typically how you'd create an object through a form like that. If you look in your logs you may see a warning saying something along these lines.

If you set the id specifically rather than using something like `p = Probe.new(params[:probe])` then you should be okay. E.g.

```
p = Probe.new(params[:probe])
p.id = param[:probe][:id]
```