# Having trouble with unit test in Rails (newbie). Strange and unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

So I am new to testing in Rails and I am having trouble understanding why this unit test fails. Basically, I expect this unit test to input one record into the test database. For some odd reason, the test fails and yet TWO records are added to the test database. This is very strange behavior. Using 'rails c test' and then typing in 'Thing.all', this is what I get prior to running the test and after running the test.

Prior to the test (after running rake db:test:prepare and then Thing.all in the rails console):

```
Thing Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" 
 => []
```

After the test:

```
Thing Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things" 
 => [#<Thing id: 980190962, name: "MyNameAgain", created_at: "2012-01-22 17:34:25", updated_at: 
"2012-01-22 17:34:25", description: "MyDescription">, #<Thing id: 298486374, name: "Hello", 
created_at: "2012-01-22 17:34:25", updated_at: "2012-01-22 17:34:25", description: 
"HelloDescription">]
```

So here is the unit test:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'awesome_print'

class ThingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  setup do
    @example = Thing.new(things(:one).attributes)
    # Must set id manually
    @example.id = things(:one).id
  end

  test 'thing can be created' do
    ap @example
    ap @example.valid?
    ap @example.errors
    assert @example.save
  end

end
```

The output from awesome print is the following:

```
#<Thing:0x007fda8c1d99f8> {
             :id => 980190962,
           :name => "MyNameAgain",
     :created_at => Sun, 22 Jan 2012 17:17:08 UTC +00:00,
     :updated_at => Sun, 22 Jan 2012 17:17:08 UTC +00:00,
    :description => "MyDescription"
}
false
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x7fda8c064000
    @base = #<Thing:0x007fda8c1d99f8> {
                 :id => 980190962,
               :name => "MyNameAgain",
         :created_at => Sun, 22 Jan 2012 17:17:08 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Sun, 22 Jan 2012 17:17:08 UTC +00:00,
        :description => "MyDescription"
    },
    attr_reader :messages = {
        :name => [
            [0] "has already been taken"
        ]
    }
>
F
Finished in 0.186603 seconds.

  1) Failure:
test_thing_can_be_created(ThingTest) [/Users/sb1752/Dropbox/Coding/GeneralAssembly/class_RubyForDevs/4-rails-mvc/4.3-rails-dev/test/unit/thing_test.rb:16]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is the fixture:

```
one:
    name: MyNameAgain
    description: MyDescription

two:
    name: Hello
    description: HelloDescription
```

Here is the model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true
end
```

Let me know if you need any more information! Thanks!

Comment: Can you display the errors that validation found?  `ap @example.errors`.  As for why the id isn't setting, it's because you are using mass assignment - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262629/ruby-on-rails-id-not-saving

Comment: Thanks @PinnyM, I checked the errors and displayed them in the post above. I made sure to set the id manually so that is actually working now. The error is still odd though. Could you have another look?

Comment: Is your test database properly being truncated or cleared per test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based the way you are wording your question, I am guessing that you don't fully understand how fixtures work.  The fixture files ('things.yml' in your case), are used to load objects *into the database* to be available as sample data during each test.  When you run Thing.all, you are seeing the models that the fixture files have created for you.

There is also no reason (probably) for you to be assigning the :id for your models during your test.  Generally, rails will create an auto-incrementing database field, and will handle setting the id for you when the item is saved. (There are exceptional cases that require your setting the id, but this is not the norm.)

To get back to your problem, here is the error message causing the failure you are seeing:

```
    :name => [
        [0] "has already been taken"
    ]
```

This is because your validation requirement `validates :name, :uniqueness => true` checks that a name is unique (not used by more than one record), and isn't going to let you reuse an existing :name - in this case one of the fixtures is already using it (the one whose attributes you are copying).  You'll either need to modify your test (change the :name of the new model you want to create), or change the validation rules.

Another option for testing you may want to consider would be to use a factory (like FactoryGirl), rather than fixtures to create your test models.