# rails 3, how can i create id field to manually enter the ID number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm create model users with fields id, name, lastname, age how I can create a model in which the field "id" is not auto-incremental ID, I need to manually enter the numbers

run scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold user id:integer name:string lastname:string age:integer
```

in form /views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

i'm insert values

```
Id: 12345
Name: paul
Lastname: rivers
Age: 24
```

but to create show:

User was successfully created.

```
Id: 1
Name: paul
Lastname: rivers
Age: 24
```

in rails server show:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Aug 18 14:26:35 -0500 2011
  Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create User", "authenticity_token"=>"C8oBqh86CPmramr5yYRoIgufaQnKMBD5SSLOIrZ1mFo=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"paul", "id"=>"12345", "lastname"=>"rivers", "age"=>"24"}}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.4ms)  describe `users`
  AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`lastname`, `name`, `age`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('rivers', 'paul', 24, '2011-08-18 19:26:35', '2011-08-18 19:26:35')
  SQL (99.2ms)  COMMIT
```

i'm view that field id not include in query

edit 1

migration is:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.string :name
      t.string :lastname
      t.integer :age

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

the id must be primary_key

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517869/id-field-without-autoincrement-option-in-migration

Comment: I would recommended you do not do this. Breaking Rails convention is not good, usually.

Answer (score 0):

edit your migration

```
create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :id
  ...
end
```

Comment: humm  but i need id is primary_key

Comment: @floor, checkout my migration, is the same.